# How to add/use a --with-package arg in an autotools project?

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I'm trying to add a mandatory path to look for headers in my autotools project. The user would configure as follows.

```
$ configure --with-newproj=/path/to/newproj
```

And then I would expect to somehow be able to use the given path in src/Makefile.am like such.

```
$ newproj_CFLAGS = -I${NEWPROJ_HOME}/include @CHECK_CFLAGS@
```

So far I have the following and this seems to output the path on the command line.

```
AC_ARG_WITH([newproj],
    AS_HELP_STRING([--with-newproj],
        [The top-level directory to the newproj installation.]),
    [with_newproj=yes],
    [with_newproj=no])

echo "==== with-newproj := \"$with_newproj\""
```

But I'm not sure how to use it in the CFLAGS line or make it mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with_newproj=yes` argument seems odd.  In the event that the user in fact provides a path, you are replacing it with the string `yes`.  In the event that they specify `--with-newproj` without specifying the path, you are being redundant with what Autoconf will do automatically.

Inasmuch as you say the path is *mandatory*, the `with_newproj=no` argument also seems odd.  In the event that the user does not specify a path, you provide `no` as the wanted path.

For the `AC_ARG_WITH`, then, something like this would be more appropriate:

```
AC_ARG_WITH([newproj],
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-newproj=<path>],
        [The top-level directory to the newproj installation.])],
    [AS_IF([test -d "$with_newproj"],
        [AC_MSG_NOTICE([Using newproj from "$with_newproj"])],
        [AC_MSG_ERROR([Specify an existing directory for newproj, not "$with_newproj"])])],
    [AC_MSG_ERROR([Use --with-newproj=<path> to specify the path to newproj])])
```

If the user provides the `--with` (or `--without`) argument then Autoconf will automatically set shell variable `with_newproj` to the value specified by the user, or to `yes` or `no`, as appropriate.  If they don't, then Autoconf will not automatically set it, and since the argument is mandatory for you, that is an error case.

But I think your main question was about how to transfer that information to the Makefile.  The central concept here is the "[output variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html#Setting-Output-Variables)".  This is a shell variable in `configure` whose value is substituted into the templates processed by `AC_OUTPUT`.  Moreover, Automake automatically provides a `make` variable for each of these (and it is idiomatic for `Makefile.am` to use these instead of using Autoconf substitutions directly).  The main Autoconf macro for setting this up is `AC_SUBST`:

```
NEWPROJ_HOME="$with_newproj"
AC_SUBST([NEWPROJ_HOME])
```